# Error in $A.getCallback() [TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key] Failing descriptor: {markup://c:Top5Clients}. Please try again

Tags: lightning, adderror

I have two components 1)Top5Clients and 2)MessagesandAlerts which retrieves recodrs from their respective custom objects

I want to display the two components side by side so I have included in a MainComp component and when I am trying to execute MainComp by putting it in a lightning application getting the abobe error

Top5Clients helper logic

```
({

    getAllClients : function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.getTop5Clients");

        action.setCallback(this, function(a){

            component.set("v.TopClients", a.getReturnValue());

        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }

})
```

messages and Alerts helper logic

```
({

    getMessagesAndAlerts : function(component, event, helper) {

        var dupac = component.get("c.getMessagesAndAlerts");

        dupac.setCallback(this, function(m){

            component.set("v.MessageAlerts", m.getReturnValue());

        });

        $A.enqueueAction(dupac);
    }

})
```

I doubt some problem in the helper methods..pls suggest
Please find the Top5Client code

```
<aura:attribute name="TopClients" type="TopClients__c[]"/>
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS202/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css"/>
<div class="slds-media__body">
  <p class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate slds-align-middle" title="Messages and Alerts">Top 5 Clients</p>

</div>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-table--cell-buffer">

        <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
        <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Name</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">AUM</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Cash</span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <aura:iteration var="client" items="{!v.TopClients}">


               <tr>
                   <td scope="col">
              {!client.Name}
                       </td>
                   <td scope="col">
              {!client.AUM__c}
                       </td>
                   <td scope="col">
              {!client.Cash__c}
                       </td>

            </tr>

     </aura:iteration>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

MessageAndAlertc code

```
    <div class="slds-media__body">
  <p class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate slds-align-middle" title="Messages and Alerts">Messages and Alerts</p>

</div>



<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-table--cell-buffer">

        <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
        <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">AlertType</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Alertsource</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">AlertDescription </span></th>
          <th  scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Account </span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">AlertDate </span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

    <aura:iteration var="client" items="{!v.MessageAlerts}">

           <tr>
                   <td scope="col">

              {!client.Alert_Type__c}
                       </td>
                   <td scope="col">
              {!client.Alert_Source__c}
                       </td>
                   <td scope="col">
              {!client.AlertDescription__c}
                       </td>
               <td scope="col">
              {!client.Account__c}
                    </td>
               <td scope="col">
              {!client.Alert_Date__c}
                    </td>
                        </tr>

     </aura:iteration>

        </tbody>


    </table>
```

Trying to print data from top5clients,messageandalert custom object

when i try to run Lightning application with top5clients and mesaagesandalert facing the error when run independently the components are working fine

```
<div class=""> 
     <div>

        <table id="page-table">
            <tr>
                <td class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 page-table-td">

                    <c:Top5Clients />        
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 page-table-td">
                 <c:MeaasgeandAlert /> 

                </td>
             </tr>
        </table>                 
     </div>

</div>
```

After the error I can see output for Top5Clients but not for messagesandalert..table printing only column headings but not data

Comment: can you share the <c:top5client/> component  code as well to debug the issue?

Comment: yes, Top5Clients's component code

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your server side controller is returning a Collection, while your component is expecting an array for the attribute "TopClients".

This might be causing issues because you're trying to convert a List into an array. Or some other incompatible data type.

Please check your server side controller

Comment: What do you mean by converting a List into an array?